# iptables forwarding between two interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

So I have a linux box with two wireless interfaces, one is a station and the other an AP.

wlan0 (station) - Connected to the internet connection

wlan1 (AP) - Other clients connect to it.

I would like for clients connected to wlan1 to be able to access the internet on wlan0. And I'd like to do this with iptables as my kernel doesn't have bridging support...

Here's what I've tried so far with iptables but it's not working:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: IPTABLES is a stateful packet-filter, it permits/drops/mangles packets.  It is not a router, or bridge.  Your commands adjust the firewall to permit the traffic, but they do not do anything to actually forward it.

Comment: So replace the kernel with one that has the features you need. It is "a linux box," after all.

Comment: Can I achieve what I'm trying to do with 'route'? I'll look into rebuilding the kernel with bridge support as well but wondering if there are other options.

Comment: Route tells it where to go once it's enabled. Michael told you what you need to do to support routing. THEN you need to turn it on via sysctl.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First, to enable hosts connecting on your private interface to go out to the internet, you don't need bridging the interfaces, you need  to route packets coming in on one interface, to the other one, where they go out to the wild.

To do that, you only need to:

1. Enable forwarding on your linux box:
2. Allow specific (or all of it) packets to traverse your router
3. As someone stated, as netfilter is a stateless firewall, allow traffic for already established connections
4. Change the source address on packets going out to the internet

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
            -j ACCEPT
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

That should do it.

Comment: I think you'd also have to set the clients to use the linux box as their gateway.

Comment: And to make the forwarding persist through reboots you want to do this: 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'

Comment: I guessed that was out of the question, if the clients where connected via wifi to this so called router.

Comment: Do you need to set those `iptables` rules if `ip_forward`ing is turned on in the kernel?

Comment: @StudentsTea Yes, you do, unless your `iptables`' `FORWARD` table is set to a globally accepting policy.  You'd still need the `nat` table rules either way though.

Comment: How might this be different if I wanted to only forward connections on a select port? (e.g. port 2222 on wlan1 to port 3333 on wlan0)?

Comment: how do you make this a permanent change?

Comment: Great answer! `--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED` is a good way to prevent simple spoofing, but  a well-crafted package  can go through pretty easily. Anything for more sophisticated spoofing protection?