# ifconfig up does not execute from cron

Tags: cron, ifconfig, network-namespace

I'm attempting to combine [Scott Lowe's guide to creating a namespace](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) with [this answer on forwarding traffic between two interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface).

I have this script that runs on each reboot using the cron @reboot directive: (I am using the script because none of these commands seem to persist across reboots.)

```
# Setup VPN
ip netns add vpnspace
ip link add vpnopen type veth peer name vpnbind
ip link set vpnopen netns vpnspace
ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up
```

When I run the script manually using `sudo`, it executes fine. However, when the script is run by cron, the fourth line, `ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up`, does not execute. Why is this happening? How do I get it to execute?

**TL;DR:** `ifconfig vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up` doesn't execute when called by cron inside a namespace

=============

Clarifications:

1. My cron job is `@reboot /home/ubuntu/startupscripts/rootscripts.sh`
2. The code given above is the first part of the shell script called
3. By "does not execute", I mean that if I run command `sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig` in the terminal to check if the IP address was brought up, terminal returns a blank output. I tried logging the output by appending `>>rootscripts.log`, but nothing is logged and no error message returned.

Comment: Not entirely familiar with the syntax here but I would have said that you don't mix `ip` and `ifconfig`. In fact `ifconfig` isn't available by default in systemd Linux systems. The consistent syntax would seem to be `ip link set vpnopen up`.

Comment: So `ip netns exec vpnspace` is a directive that tells the following command to execute inside the `vpnspace` namespace. Everything after is the same.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood - Your solution works so far that the code executes from cron, but how would I assign the interface an IP address?

Comment: `ip link set vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up`

Comment: Tried it before I asked. Didn't do the trick. :/

Comment: Does it return an error?

Comment: What does "does not execute" mean exactly? What is the error message you get? Differences between running in a terminal and via cron are usually attributable to the environment. Also, do you run these commands together as a script via cron or do you have multiple cron entries running independently?

Comment: On another note, did you run `ip link set vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up` or rather `ip netns exec vpnspace ip link set vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up`?

Comment: cron commands typically execute with a default PATH.  While ip is typically in /bin, ifconfig is typically in /sbin . . . so try putting /sbin/ifconfig in your command line.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood - No error that I can see. I logged the output to check.

Comment: @OlafDietsche - See clarification edits. Also, I ran [1] `ip netns exec vpnspace ip link set vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up` from the script and then [2] `sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ip link show` and [3] `sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig` to check it.  [2] returns that the interface is established, but [3] shows that no IP address is assigned. Compared to my original version (`sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig`), both [2] and [3] would return an empty result.

Comment: Maybe this is taking it from a different angle, but should/could I be calling this script to run on startup by some other means than cron, if calling the command from cron is the issue?

Comment: @BrandonXavier - `ip netns exec vpnspace /sbin/ifconfig vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up` did it! Will you submit as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron commands usually execute with a default PATH. While ip is typically in /bin, ifconfig is most often found  in /sbin . . . so try putting /sbin/ifconfig in your command line.

Comment: It's still a very good idea to rewrite this to use `ip` instead of `ifconfig`, which might not even be installed on a modern Linux system. Later `ifconfig` might not even be packaged and distributed anymore.