# How to route internet to an interface ppp0 that I called to?

Tags: iptables, route, point-to-point-protocol

My scenario is:

- `host1` has internet connection through interface `eth0`;
- `host1` dial up `host2` and establishes a PPP connection with it;
- `host2` has no internet access;
- `host1` needs to share internet connection with `host2` using this interface `ppp0`;

So, I think that basically we have this:

`(internet) <eth0> === host1 === <ppp0> === host2`

This is from `host1`:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7409  bytes 29789661 (28.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5933  bytes 422162 (412.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 28  bytes 2352 (2.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 2352 (2.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.100.0.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 5  bytes 78 (78.0 B)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 90 (90.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is from `host2`:

```
# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet 10.100.0.1  P-t-P: 10.100.0.2 Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
```

I tried to use `iptables` to forward the traffic between interface, as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface?newreg=930ea9186a2d404b8f69e0f4c872bbd7).

In `host2` I added default route for dev `ppp0` using gw `10.100.0.2`, which is that ip of `host1`.

Any suggestion? I am really not used to networking techniques.

I think the most important remarks are:

- `host1` is the one that calls `host2`;
- on `host1` I can do whathever I want, however `host2` has a read-only file system, I can only add routes and change minor stuff;

Answer (score 1):

This set up is some how tricky :

If `host1` was the one acting as ppp server then the problem would be easy to solve. Just configure the ppp daemon to push a default route to the client

But since `host1` is the one calling `host2` I don't see how `host1` could push a default route (and setting this manually is not really acceptable) unless ...

For me the solution is to use a routing protocol process (rip or ospf) so that when to link is up these processes agree on an adequate routing tables

Finally the NAT has to include all the used IP ranges in order to reach the Internet

Comment: Hi @Soulimane, thanks for your answer. I am starting to realize this is definitely a tricky set up as you pointed out, lucky me :) ... Say I could set the default route manually, something like `route add default gw 10.100.0.2 ppp0` (which I can since I have physical access to `host2` for now), what else should I do? It seems to be not enough.
Thanks for telling me about rip and pspf, I will give a check on them.

Comment: If you choose to set the default route manually each time you bring the ppp link up (which is not at all convenient), you have to add a  route for  ``10.100.0.0/32`` to you Internet router and NAT this subnet as well