# Ubuntu 20.04 forward traffic between two interfaces (wlan0 and eth0) using NetworkManager

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, ip, networkmanager

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Pi with netplan disabled and using NetworkManager only.
Have wlan0 running in AP mode and an ethernet cable connected to the Pi.

I want connections made to the wifi AP on wlan0 to be able to access the internet via eth0.

I believe this would be accomplished by forwarding traffic between wlan0 and eth0.

I've tried using iptables as mentioned in many other answers, but I can't seem to get it to work.
This didn't work: [iptables forwarding between two interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface)

Is there a strictly NetworkManager way to do this?

***NOTE: I've literally tried about 10 or so walkthroughs I've found online using nmcli, iptables, brctl and ip. Nothing is working.
I will give somebody all of my reputation if I an answer is provided that gets this working.***

Comment: Please, if you are going to downvote the question it would be helpful to say what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
systemd-resolved was getting in the way of DNS working properly.
So I disabled systemd-resolved and all is working as expected.

Apparently systemd-resolved doesn't play nicely with Network Manager.