# How to NAT-route network to Tailscale?

Tags: iptables, router, route, static-routes, tailscale

**EDIT:** I already spent 3 days going through different possible ways of handling this and settled on `iptables`. This is like the biggest-kept secret to me. No matter how much I read, I feel like I'm missing some critical information to doing something as simple as pre- and post-routing redirection.

---

I want to send 100% of the network traffic for `PC-A` in one location to `PC-B` in another location using `PC-R` as a Tailscale router. I will most likely need an `iptables` configuration.

The setup:

1. `PC-A` cannot run Tailscale.
2. `PC-R`, the router, will be a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with a single Ethernet NIC.
3. The Raspberry Pi is connected to a Tailscale network which creates a `tailscale0` virtual interface.
4. All incoming traffic is sent from the Raspberry Pi to a Tailscale exit node (similar to how other VPNs can securely send all your network traffic).

The gateway on `PC-A` will be set to `PC-R`'s `eth0` (LAN) since `tailscale0` is virtual (and therefore not able to be accessed by PC-A).

Because `PC-A` is sending data to `PC-R`'s `eth0`, I need to route all `PC-R`'s incoming traffic to `tailscale0` and visa versa.

Knowing this, **how do I set up `iptables` or similar to route incoming traffic on `eth0` to `tailscale0`?**

Comment: You literally ask us to do your job of reading the configuration. Bad news: 
Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: I've spent 3 days on this problem going from TrueNAS running Tailscale to OpenWRT to pfSense, and today, Raspbian w/ iptables. Telling the whole history of how I got to needing iptables won't get answered. That's why I simplified and said "PC-A, PC-B, I have a router in-between, how do I route packets?". Much simpler. I'm expecting someone to say `iptables -t nat PRE something` and `iptables -t nat POST something`. That's all I need to figure out. None of this has to do with Tailscale specifically. If I said OpenVPN, it would be the same issue. I need to NAT route a virtual interface.

Comment: And the answer would be the same. You babbling around 3 days because it takes you more to learn the basics properly is not our problem. You can take 3years to do what others do in a week (reading documentation and understanding ip routing) - that does not make the question valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching more, I found nearly the exact same question answered here without any sus: https://serverfault.com/a/431607/189877.

After testing through everything, this is my solution:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tailscale0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Not sure exactly what this does. To remove it, do this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o tailscale0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Note the `-D`.

`-A` appends and `-D` deletes. It's the same command otherwise.

The rule is only temporary and will be gone after a restart. You may need `iptables-persistent` to keep it around. Not actually sure how to properly keep iptables rules after a restart though.